# How can I go to a thermal bath in Merano?

Tags: italy, nudism, hot-springs, radiation

Do I need to book a room from a hotel?
Are there any public ones?
What is the cost?
Should I expect nudity in saunas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a Thermal Spa Centre!

The new thermal spa centre, on the opposite bank of the river Passirio, was opened during the 1970’s and is furnished with the most modern equipment for therapeutic treatment. It also houses an indoor swimming-pool filled with thermal water and the natural radio-activity in this water has a most beneficial pathological effect. The spa centre is open all year round and specialises in a vast selection of curative treatments.

[More information on the Thermal Spa Baths.](http://www.merano.info/en/meran-thermal-baths.html)

[Official Site of Therme Meran](http://thermemeran.it/index.php?lang=3)

Prices range depending on whether you want a spa, a bath, and for how long.  [This page has a list of prices](http://thermemeran.it/orari_generali.php).

There certainly doesn't appear to be any indication of nudity.

Comment: Well, the Sauna has to be used "au naturel" However, for the other installations swimwear is compulsory. Bathing caps are not required.

Comment: Why go to a thermal spa bath in Italy when you can go to one in Fukushima province? http://blogs.wsj.com/japanrealtime/2012/03/09/march-11-one-year-on-radium-hot-springs-still-in-demand/ links to http://www.rajiumu-onsen.net/fukusima/index.html

Comment: because when you're in Italy, Japan is rather far....

Comment: The Sauna is separate from the pools: it has a different access, and you can enter only if you are 18+. There is a nudist sunbathing area, fenced, and you are required to NOT wear a swimming costume inside, but you may wear a towel to cover yourself if you desire.